# Swapping laptops while keeping current systems (kernel)

Tags: images, operating-systems, kernel, data-transfer

I am going to be getting a new laptop from HP soon, due to a faulty part, and they are giving my an upgrade.  Almost all of the specifications will be changing, but I'm not keen on reinstalling my operating systems again.  Currently, I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 on my computer.  The kernels of the two operating systems live on an SSD, and most of the data (and some of the programs) live on a 1TB secondary internal drive.

My questions are as follows.

Can I move the hard drives over to the new computer and have a reasonable chance of the kernel adapting (with minimal pain) to new hardware?

If I can't, how should I go about imaging my hard drives in order to keep the most data?  I have symlinks across the drives, and some programs are installed on the secondary drive.

Are there other options for me to keep my operating systems without virtualizing them (which goes back to the imaging question)?

Old computer

```
HP dv7-6b73nr
```

New computer

```
HP dv7-7012nr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a while ago, but the answer was yes. I swapped the drives, and things worked pretty well. There were some bumps and reconfigurations, but Ubuntu worked pretty well. Windows fell on its face and made me reinstall.